# Leaderboard.getEntriesAsync - request failed for >=20 entries

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I've noticed that "getEntriesAsync" (API 6.0) method for leaderboards throws "Request failed to be processed" error when I request about >=18 scores from leaderboard with around 300k of players.

In my game, I'm requesting exactly 20 entries, and sometimes it works sometimes not. So, It looks like it depends on "count" parameter and server load. But according to docs, the safe limit for one query should be 100 entries.

Can anyone at Facebook take a look on this issue, please?

Comment: If you're trying to reach Facebook, you may want to contact them directly.  There's no guarantee Facebook engineers will see this.

Comment: _“But according to docs, the safe limit for one query should be 100 entries”_ - not sure which section exactly you are referring to here; but I am pretty sure that is only the maximum limit value you can specify - it does not mean that you will get that many results without error. If you check the actual API response, it will likely be an error message saying that you requested too much data, and should try to request less. This is not really about the 18 or 20 actual values you get returned, but how much resources it takes to retrieve those values in the first place (300k players ...)

Comment: I'm referring to "count - number The number of entries to attempt to fetch from the leaderboard. Defaults to 10 if not specified. Up to a maximum of 100 entries may be fetched per query."
In my game everything works great when I call:
leaderboard.getEntriesAsync(15, 0)
but for:
leaderboard.getEntriesAsync(30, 0)
I've got:
code: "NETWORK_FAILURE"
message: "Request failed to be processed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Instant Games at Facebook and we discovered this was actually a bug in our code that was mishandling a fringe privacy condition. We have made a change to remove scores for users who you cannot see from a privacy perspective (previously this was causing the entire request to fail).

Comment: Chris, I can confirm that getEntriesAsync works like a charm, now. I can ask even for 100 records without any issues. Thanks for the quick fix!